# Approach on finding the Fourier series solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Given the expression:
$u(x,t) =e^{-Ct} y(x,t) - v(t)$

How would one approach this when looking for the Fourier series solution, or where to start?

Is it possible to see from this which Fourier coefficients would equal zero allready?

**With the following conditions:**

$C > 0 ,\qquad 0 < t, \qquad 0 \le x  \le 1$

$y(0,t) = y(1,t) = 0 = u(0,t) = u(1,t)$

$y(0,0) = y(1,0) = 0 = v(0) = v(1)$

Don't know if this is of importance:

$v = v(x)$ satisfies: $v''-Cv=-f(x)$

$u = u(x,t)$ satisfies: $u_{xx} = u_{tt}-Cu= f(x)$